# Capistrano release not publishing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, capistrano, continuous-deployment

I am trying to deploy my Rails application to my remote test environment with Capistrano.  I am using Git as my deploy source.

When I run `cap development deploy` everything appears to work.  In my local log, I even see the new release supposedly deploy.

> INFO [887154fa] Running /usr/bin/env echo "Branch dev deployed as release 20131219020401 by Clay; "

When I log into my remote server to validate the deploy of the release, I expect to see my web application updated.  Instead, my latest commits have not been deployed.  What is more curious is if I navigate to the remote `myapp/releases` folder I can see my release.

Why is this release not being published?

**deploy.rb**

```
require "capistrano/rvm"

set :rvm_ruby_string, :local           
set :rvm_autolibs_flag, "read-only" 
set :stages, %w(development, test, production)
set :default_stage, "development"
set :application, 'myapp'
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:cometman/myapp.git'
set :deploy_to, '/var/www/myapp'
set :scm, :git
set :branch, "dev"
set :deploy_via, :copy
set :keep_releases, 5
```

Comment: Are these commits in `dev` branch?

Comment: Yes, I am pushing to the dev branch.

Comment: So your latest changes are in `releases` or in `current`? Maybe you're deploying fine, but running wrong version on server? What server are you using?

Comment: Latest version is in releases.  When you say wrong version, do you mean wrong branch?  My original goal was to to push to "dev" and have my CI environment run all of its unit tests.  Upon success, these changes would be pushed to test and CI tests would be run again.  Finally, the test branch would be published to my test server.  

Since this was not working, I cut out the push to test piece and was attempting to push to dev, run CI suite, and deploy to dev on my server.

Comment: I mean you've deployed properly but nginx (or whatever is running there) is pointed to wrong release (other than current) so that's why you see older app live despite of newer capistrano deploy.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that.  I am running Apache Passenger.  It is correctly pointed to my app's directory.  Should this instead be pointed at the releases folder (that seems very weird to me if so...)?

Comment: No, it should be pointed at `current`, if it is so and code in that directory contains your commits (and Passanger is restarted after deploy) then I don't know what can cause that issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last step in a capistrano deployment is `symlink`ing the working release directory from `/app/releases/[TIMESTAMP]` => `/app/current`.  If this symlink has not been updated, but you see a release in the releases directory, something has failed along the way.

If you paste the entire logs of your deploy, I can help you find what has failed.  You will need to solve the root cause of this failure in order to see a successful, complete deploy.

Comment: I will validate this shortly and get back to you!

Comment: I ended up wiping capistrano out and reinstalling it.  That fixed the problem.  Your answer clued me in that I probably had some things wrong in my environment.  Thanks for the help.